# how to analyze tensorflow timeline tracing: GPU have a big mount of free time

Tags: tensorflow

I add profile code(timeline) by following this [Profiling tools for open source TensorFlow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmqhD.png)

after I get the chrome trace file, I open it in chrome(chrome://tracing/). 
here is my result:
[image]
You can see that there are some big chunk of free time in GPU.

**My question is: why GPU not doing anything?**

here is my code:

```
                batch_x,batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(FLAGS.batch_size)
            run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()
            _,loss,summary,step = sess.run([train_op, total_loss,summary_op,global_step],
                    feed_dict={x:batch_x.reshape([FLAGS.batch_size,IMAGE_SIZE,IMAGE_SIZE,NUM_CHANNELS]),y:batch_y},
                    options=tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE),
                    run_metadata=run_metadata)
            writer.add_summary(summary,step)
```

I google around, many people **think this maybe caused by feed_dict, because it is not a recommended way of feeding data. But I can not find any proof from this timeline**.

I  use line_profile to profile this function, the data fetch action:

```
batch_x,batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(FLAGS.batch_size)
```

only takes 0.3 ms. Can someone help me find out why? any suggestion is welcome.